# Robot_localization ekf vs ukf process noise

Tags: navigation, ekf, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Attempting to compare results from both ekf and ukf (ubuntu, indigo).  Would one expect to use the same process noise covariance matrix for both?  Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249418/robot_localization-ekf-vs-ukf-process-noise/) by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2016-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both filters use the same process noise covariance matrix parameter. However, I'm guessing what you're asking is whether the output estimate error covariance matrices would be the same for the UKF and EKF. I've never done any analysis, but I would expect them to be similar, but certainly not identical. They use different methods for projecting the state and error covariance matrices forward during prediction.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on 2016-12-21**:
Thank you Tom.  That verifies my assumptions.  Still tuning Q matrix and hoped that effort would apply to both ekf and ukf.  Regards.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-01-04**:
I'd say that if you use the same `process_noise_covariance` for both/either, then that ought to work.